# AudioDeviceCmdlets sucessfully (?) installed but unable to execute

Tags: windows, powershell

I've installed AudioDeviceCmdlets. It shows as a Module in Powershell ISE V5. Get-AudioDevice, Set-AudioDevice, and Write-AudioDevice are all present, together with their applicable parameters (List, Index, ID, ...). Get-AudioDevice Help also displays the different Synopsis.

When I try to execute (e.g., Get-AudioDevice -List), however, I'm getting "Element not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)". I can't figure out what the problem is - could it be this is somehow not supported in Windows 11?

FYI, I've also tried executing the Cmdlets in VS Code with Powershell 7.2 installed, but seeing same issue.

Thank you.

Comment: `Get-Help` imports the module in the background when ran against a cmdlet of that module; so the module not being loaded wouldn't be the issue, but you never know. Can you run `Get-Module` to list the currently loaded modules and see if it's there? I am also on win11 with 7.2 and can run it just fine

Comment: Installed, and imported are different scenarios. Can you see them using `Get-Module -ListAvailable`?

Answer (score 0):

While 'Get-AudioDevice -List' results in an error, 'Set-AudioDevice -Index 1' runs without error (assuming this speaker is set as Default). If "Speaker Set 2" is set as default, then 'Set-AudioDevice -Index 1' will result in an error. Since at least one speaker set will always be inactive, 'Get-AudioDevice -List' errrors-out.